# Next.js application routes with the term localhost in the deployed server

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js, keycloak, next-auth

When I deployed my next.js application in a Kubernetes pod, The application routed and redirected with  localhost:3000 in my deployed environment too. I need to authorize my requests via keycloak. So I'm using keycloak v21.1.1. When my application is going to call the keycloak for authorization, Then I'm getting this barrier.

The below code snippet shows my middleware.ts class.

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware"

export default withAuth({
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ req, token }) {
      if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/admin") {
        return token?.userRole === "admin"
      }
      return !!token
    },
  },
})

// refactored for deployment purposes
export const config = { matcher: ["/pages/:path*"] }
```

The below code shows the next.config.js

```
const nextConfig = {
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/',
                destination: '/pages/PortfolioStatement',
                permanent: true,  // Change to false if this redirect is temporary
            },
        ]
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

What I'm expecting is not to show the host as localhost in the QA environment